# How to count the number of boxing and unboxing operations

Tags: java, autoboxing

I have a loop like this

```
        int length = 1000000000;
        Integer sum1 = 0;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sum1  = sum1 + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(sum1);
```

How do I count the number of boxing and unboxing operations here?
Here are what I guess to be boxing and unboxing

boxing:

1. `i++` boxes `i + 1` to `Integer`
2. `sum1 + 1` is boxed to Integer

unboxing:

1. `i < length` unboxes `i` to `int`

Am I correct for above? And how can I programmatically count the number of boxing and unboxing operations?

Comment: `i < length` and `i++` are going to execute 1000000000 times and `sum1  = sum1 + 1;` is going to execute (1000000000 - 1). Hopefully you can see the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If *sum1* is always incremented by 1 and at beginning of program is always zero, then *sum1* is actually the number of boxed operation performed with sum1.
Operation on *sum1* is shorter:

**--> sum1=sum1+1;-->sum1+=1-->sum1++;**

So if *sum1* is number of boxed operation performed with *sum1*, then we can assume that with *i++* operation number of boxed operation on *i* is actually *i*.
For loop always checks condition

**i<length**

, so we know it will check this *length* times. You might think that it iterates through *lenth-1* times, but actually it checks and last, not fullfiled condition.

So we may conclude that:

**number_unboxed_operations=length,
number_boxed_operations=i+sum1.**

If operation on *sum1* is indeed different(sum1+=2), we can ask ourselfs how much time will condition be true.

Condition will be true until *i==length* so for *sum1* operation will be performed *lenth-1* times;